# Magento 2: How virtual product hide shipping step?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, virtual-products

I want to know how shipping step is skipped on checkout page for virtual product. I know virtual product skips shipping step on checkout page but how it it works internally.

Acually I want to apply same functionality for bundle product but firstly I want to know real working of skipping shipping step for virtual product.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so you should start with understanding how checkout works:

1. When you add any product to cart you will create a quote object.
2. This object contains quote items, which have a `is_virtual` property.
3. When you switch to checkout, quote is loaded to a JavaScript model object. This model is used throughout checkout.
4. The JS quote model has a method called `isVirtual()` which returns true if all quote items are virtual.
5. First step of checkout has a Knockout.js `visible` property which depends on the `isVirtual()` method. When quote is virtual, then the first step is hidden.

That's it in a nutshell. :)